# change type of widget with django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I am new in Django and I want to change the input field type using django crispy-forms

MODEL

```
class Config(models.Model):
    id_proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor,db_column='id_proveedor', primary_key=True)
    d_recepcion = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='recepcion')
    d_carga_archivo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Carga de Archivo')
    d_conciliacion = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Conciliacion')
    d_envio_conci = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Envio Conciliacion')
    d_repro_completo = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Reproceso')
    d_acepta = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Aceptacion')
    d_gen_certificado = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Certificado')
    d_entrega_certificado = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Entrega Cetificado')
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_configuracion'

FORM
class ConfigForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(ConfigForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('id_proveedor',
                  readonly = True
             ),
            Fieldset('Configuracion Proveedor',
                     'd_recepcion',
                     'd_carga_archivo',
                     'd_conciliacion',
                     'd_envio_conciliacion',
                     'd_repro_completo',
                     'd_acepta',
                     'd_gen_certificado',
                     'd_entrega_certificado',
                     Submit('save','Grabar')
             )
       )
    class Meta:
        model = Config

VIEW(edit form view)
def configView(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('idprov')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       c = Config.objects.get(id_proveedor=pk)
       form = ConfigForm(request.POST, instance=c)
       if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')
    else:
       c = Config.objects.get(id_proveedor=pk)
       form = ConfigForm(instance=c)
    return render_to_response('config.html',{'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

You can see in my model the field id_proveedor is a foreign key to another model. when I render the form the the field id_proveedor use a drop down (select widget) with the name of the providers(proveedores). That looks fine in the new config form but in the edit config form I need to display the name of the provider in a Label instead of the select widget.

I try to change the widget type to a label and the form display the value of the id_proeedor(1,2 etc) instead the name of the provider and if I let to render the select widget as readonly the widget always work and the user if capable to use it like I am not using the readonly property.

I need to display the name of the provider in the edit config form in a label.

I don't know if I need to create a custom widget or there is a way to get this with the helpers of crispy-forms or if I need to change my view.

Any advice please

THANKS IN ADVANCE

P.D.: my other model is a simple model with two fields "id_proveedor"(integer and primary key) and  "provider_name"(charfield length =50)